# Reshape a 3D array extracted from NC files

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I extracted a NC file that contains 3 variables, namely longitude, latitude and time. here is the code:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

air = Dataset('tmax_0.5_daily_2012-2012.nc', 'r')
dims = air.dimensions
ndims = len(dims)
vars = air.variables
nvars = len(vars)
attrs = air.ncattrs
lon = air.variables['lon'][:]
lat = air.variables['lat'][:]
time = air.variables['time'][:]
```

the dimensions of lon, lat and time are 360, 720 and 366. while I try to extract a specific location "air" data with the code bellow it works fine and give me an 1D array with air data from time 0 to 366.

```
variable = air.variables['air'][:,23, 50]
```

where the : is time ( from start to end ) and 23 and 50 are the index numbers of a specific longitude and latitude.

However, when I need to extract the data from more than one location the code bellow must be run:

```
variable = air.variables['air'][:,23:30, 50:55]
```

This will give me a 3D array with 35 cells (7(23:30) X 5(50:55)) and 366 as Z dimension (time).

My question is how can I extract this 3D array to excel, in the form that each cell "air" value from time 0 to 366 sort under 1 column, and the dataset includes 35 columns (as the number of cells) with their corresponding value bellows them from the start of time to end.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBRHH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Numpy [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) with `(366, -1)`, where `-1` indicates to Numpy that the remaining dimension must be inferred from the length of the array.

```py
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# using a similar dataset
# http://schubert.atmos.colostate.edu/~cslocum/netcdf_example.html
air = Dataset('air.sig995.2012.nc', 'r')
print(np.array(air.variables['air']).shape)
# (366, 73, 144)

variable = np.array(air.variables['air'][:,23:30, 50:55])
print(variable.shape)
# (366, 7, 5)

x = variable.reshape(366,-1)
print(x.shape)
# (366, 35)

df = pd.DataFrame(x)
print(df)
df.to_excel('output.xls')
```

Output from *df*

```py
             0           1           2   ...          32          33          34
0    280.070007  280.350006  280.970001  ...  299.779999  299.630005  299.380005
1    279.470001  280.080017  280.650024  ...  298.429993  299.229980  299.220001
2    279.570007  279.880005  280.400024  ...  298.450012  299.220001  299.549988
..          ...         ...         ...  ...         ...         ...         ...
363  281.400024  282.770020  284.200012  ...  298.450012  298.350006  298.669983
364  277.250000  278.150024  279.369995  ...  298.549988  298.520020  298.520020
365  278.070007  277.520020  277.179993  ...  298.080017  298.799988  299.200012

[366 rows x 35 columns]
```